# Port 8000 vs Port 8080

Tags: http

I'm currently working my way through several basic web server examples with both .NET and also Python.  Most examples seem to use 8000 or 8080 as test ports.  Can anybody clarify the difference between these?  Does it matter?  Please advise.

Comment: A server can open whichever port it likes.  `8000` and `8080` are common HTTP ports for many web servers (Tomcat included among them).

Comment: Both port 8000 and 8080 are above the so-called well-known ports below 1024, and, as you noticed, both are common ports to use for web servers. Barring circumstances like firewalls or port forwarding, it does not matter which of these ports you use.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't matter. In fact, 8080 is often used as a default http port for software providing http services that is not a core http Server (e.g. Apache http Server). So after a while this port is sometimes taken from software that runs on the system in a background.
8000 it seems is just another port being used by the .NET domain.
Ports below 1024 need system user permission like root or something. That is why ports in the thousands are used for software running as a normal user.

Answer (score 2):

No difference. Two common ports you'll want to know the difference between  80 and 443. 80 is for insecure (HTTP) connections and the other one is for secure (HTTPS) connections, but they both are used and reserved for HTTP communication.